# Cannot remove duplicates from a list using Python

Tags: python

I have a csv file which I want to edit so I read the file and copy the contents in a list. The list contains duplicates. So I do:

```
csv_in = list(set(csv_in))
```

But I get:

Unhashable list Error

```
with open(source_initial2, 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as file_in, open(source_initial3, 'w', encoding='ISO-8859-1',newline='') as file_out:
  csv_in = csv.reader(file_in, delimiter=',')
  csv_out = csv.writer(file_out, delimiter=';')
  csv_in = list(set(csv_in))


for row in csv_in:

    for i in range(len(row)):
        if "/" in row[i]:
            row[i] = row[i].replace('/', '')

        if "\"" in row[i]:
            row[i] = row[i].replace('\"', '')
        if "Yes" in row[i]:
            row[i] = row[i].replace('Yes', '1')
        if "No" in row[i]:
            row[i] = row[i].replace('No', '0')
        if myrowlen > 5:
            break
    print(row)    
    csv_out.writerow(row)
```

The list is something like

[['DCA.P/C.05820', '5707119001793', 'P/C STEELSERIES SUR... QcK MINI', '5,4', 'Yes'],['DCA.P/C.05820', '5707119001793', 'P/C STEELSERIES SUR... QcK MINI', '5,4', 'Yes'].....['DCA.P/C.05820', '5707119001793', 'P/C STEELSERIES SUR... QcK MINI', '5,4', 'Yes']]

Why I get this, how can I solve it?
thank you

Comment: can you show me the structure of your list what inside of that list?

list in the list like [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] or tuple in list 

but I recommend using pandas to remove duplicate

Comment: `csv_in` is probably a list of lists. Lists are unhashable, so you have to convert the inner list to a tuple (hashable) to make a set out of the outer. Try this: `csv_in = list(set(tuple(inner) for inner in csv_in))`

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have is that `csv_in` is a list of lists and list is not hashable datatype. In order to get around the issue you can do the following:

```
csv_in = list(set([tuple(row) for row in csv_in]))
```

or if you need it as a list of lists:

```
csv_in = [list(element) for element in set([tuple(row) for row in csv_in])]
```

Answer (score 1):

`csv.reader` contains rows where each ***row*** read from the csv file is returned as a **list** of strings.

While `set` object requires its items to be an immutable data type (thereby *hashable*), `list` type is not one of those.

```
test_reader = [[0,1,2], [3,4,5]]
print(set(test_reader))  # throws TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

# after casting to tuple type
test_reader = [(0,1,2), (3,4,5)]
print(set(test_reader))   # {(0, 1, 2), (3, 4, 5)}
```

Comment: And If I want to change an element of tuple I should do test_reader[0][1] for number 1 correct?

Comment: @MariaGeorgali, 'tuple' object does not support item assignment, but after a tuple is  converted into a set - that set can be updated, but not assigned

Comment: So how can I change in your example the values 0,1,2 ?

Comment: @MariaGeorgali, I can definitely make your approach to be more concise, readable and optimized - if you posted a testable csv file fragment and the final expected result

Comment: Please consider the bottom part of my question. The csv contains those values and I need to change for example the P/C to PC or omit a list row containing the word of steelseries

Comment: @MariaGeorgali, the bottom part is mangled, just post the initial csv raw text data so I could "open" (convert) it as a file object